# What is the token id?

Tags: polygon

Total crypto newb here, I would appreciate some clarifications about the tokenid on both the ethereum and polygon blockchains.

1. I keep seeing this definition of tokenid, is the tokenid made up of the contract address and the token id?
2. Will the tokenid will remain the same even after multiple transfers even across different blockchains?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've been working for 4 years on Ethereum-related projects, and I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "token id". It's perhaps related to ERC-721 non-fungible tokens, but if you want us to be able to answer your question, you need to add more details. Where have you seen this? Share a link to some code.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right, I mean the ERC-721 non-fungible tokens that we can mint on Opensea. I am wondering if the tokenid will remain the same even after multiple transactions, I am concerned about the buyer being able to track the legitimacy of the NFT after multiple transactions. So I am wondering if the tokenid will consist of the contract address and the tokenid?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering how do you track an NFT through the blockchain? Is it through a tokenid? And if it is tracked by its tokenid, I would like to know exactly what makes up a tokenid and whether this tokenid remains the same on the polygon and Ethereum Blockchain after each transaction.

Comment: Whether it remains the same across blockchains may depend upon the implementation. The original spec did not mention what implementors should do when they want to port the NFT to other blockchains. For your other questions, I recommend reading the [ERC-721 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721).

Comment: I was looking at Opensea to mint some NFTs. They use the ERC-721 standard. But they did not state how you would identify whether the NFT is the same NFT you minted once it has been transferred multiple times. I would just like to know under the ERC-721 standard, does the contract address and tokenid remain the same even after multiple transfers?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you mint an NFT a token id must be generated. For the Ethereum and Polygon chains (following the ERC-721 standard), this is a 256-bit, unsigned integer. Within a collection, these numbers are unique. If the NFT is transferred to another owner, the token id remains the same, as this number is its identifier within a collection.

Together, the token id and contract address provide a globally unique representation of the NFT (token) on that chain upon which the NFT was minted.

More detail here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-721/

Answer (score 0):

All NFTs have a uint256 variable called tokenId, so for any ERC-721 Contract, the pair contract address, uint256 tokenId must be globally unique. That said, a dapp can have a "converter" that uses the tokenId as input and outputs an image of something cool, like zombies, weapons, skills or amazing kitties!

more:https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-721/